# Spring Security with Keycloak check if the user is logged-in

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, openid-connect

In my web application, I'm using Keycloak as an authentication provider. I'm showing the additional content in the header for logged-in users. Sometimes users are already authenticated in Keycloak before visiting my app.

How can I check if a user is authenticated in Keycloak on a public page, without the user navigating to some protected page, or going to the login page before?